# Where are Email-to-Case Attachments Stored?

Tags: files, email2case

Attachments to an email-to-case email are displayed as Files but are not stored as Files or as Attachments. Can anyone tell me in which object those attachments are stored?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Email-to-Case Settings `Save Email-to-Case attachments as Salesforce Files` checked true.

Files are saved as:

- `ContentVersion`
- `ContentDocument` (parent of ContentVersion)

and linked to the EmailMessage child of the Case using a

- `ContentDocumentLink`

You can see the Schema here in the [Salesforce Object Ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_content.htm)

Comment: Apparently, attachments in an email-to-case are NOT stored there. There is no reference to the attachments (files) in any of those three objects. If you upload a file to a Case, it does get stored there.

Comment: I modified my answer